# Concatenate merged cells in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have this situation in google sheets.
[image]

I want to concatenate Row 1 and Row 2 to generate a data validation list to be used as a dropdown in another tab. The concatenate result should like Expected Results. I am not able to figure out a formula for this. Please help. I've added a link to the sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m572P3bvLe3l8fpXRrL0MceW-lrVIBLcgHXO4jOAJnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does `=index(D1&" - "&D2:H2)` suffice here? If aint please do share a sample sheet recreating the input+expected output (**manually entered**) for us to get a clear picture. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, thanks I've added a link to the sample sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=index(scan(,B1:1,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))&"-"&B2:2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Can you please explain the formula?

Comment: Once you get a picture of what *SCAN()* does; its pretty much a straight forward formula. [this vid](https://youtu.be/Fuf3U9LCOoQ) and/or [this article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/scan-function/) should be helpful. basic explanation of the above used formula for scan is *if B1:1 has something in the cell(non-blank)-> show that value-> if its blank cell-> use the value saved in accumulator which would be previous-nearest-non-blank value*